# Does a TableView inside CollectionViewCell reuses its cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UITableView inside a `UICollectionViewCell` which has more than 100 items. Does this `UICollectionViewCell` cell holds all 100 cells of `UITableView` in memory when this cell is in display? or `dequeueReusableCell` concept of `UITableViewCell` cell still apply.

Comment: Try it. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

The table view only shows what is currently on screen : so if your table view is scrollable, you shouldn't have to worry